# Deleting User Input from text file using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with a Batch script im trying to make. I've searched soon the whole Internet reading about diffrent ways to remove text from within a text file, but I can't seem to get it right.

The code I have problem with is:

```
:delete
set /p dnr=Write what you want to delete?
for /f "tokens= delims= " %%c in (document.txt) do (
set str=%%c
)
find /v "!str!" < document.txt > deleted.txt
pause
goto :begin
```

The code does not return any error, and does move the text to the "deleted.txt" but I can't seem to make it acually delete the record from document.txt.

If anyone could point me in the right direction would be much appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that %str% contains the last (non empty) line of document.txt, but not the string you want to delete (it's %dnr%).
To use the delayed expansion (!dnr!) instead of %dnr% is better, to preserve the special characters in dnr

```
:delete
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p dnr=Write what you want to delete?
find /v "!dnr!" document.txt > deleted.txt
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's acually still not deleting the record in document.txt

Comment: The document contains something like this:

1234
4321
1111
5555

and the user wants to delete the 1234. it creates the deleted.txt with the 1234 input, but the input is still present in document.txt.

Comment: @James you should look at the OUTPUT (deleted.txt). The input file (document.txt) remains unchanged!!

Comment: +1 I spent a few minutes trying to figure out why the "for" loop ... :)

Comment: Yes I know the it moves everything to the Output-file. But I also need it to delete the record in document.txt :(

Comment: Why not copy deleted.txt to document.txt at the end?

Comment: Cause that would not help me at all. Lets remove the > deleted.txt, lets pretend that's not there. I need to make this piece of code take the Users Input and DELETE that record  from document.txt.

Comment: You can not remove lines from a file without rewrite the file. And you can not rewrite a file, while reading it, so you need a temporary file

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are read using %var%, so you need to change that line to

```
find /v "%str%" < document.txt > deleted.txt
```

Also, I doubt if it is necessary to use the < before document.txt. You should be able to omit it.

Comment: Still doing the same thing. Creating the deleted.txt with the input, but not deleting the input from document.txt.